# Esperar respuestas Fetch para continuar JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo solicitudes con FETCH y voy guardando las respuestas en un array, pero quiero llamar al metodo **navigator['share']** solo cuando termine la iteracion:

```
  async compartir(images) {
    let filesArray = []

    images.forEach( async (element) => {
      const tmp = element.src.split('/')
      const name = tmp[tmp.length - 1];
      
      const response = await fetch(element.src);
      const blob = await response.blob();
  
      filesArray.push(new File([blob],name, {type: "image/jpeg",lastModified: new Date().getTime()}))     
    })
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(filesArray);      
      navigator['share']({files: filesArray, title: 'PAGINA DEL PRODUCTO', text: 'texto', url:  '' })      
    }, 3000);    
  }
```

por ahora uso un settimeout para que espere pero se que no es la mejor forma.

Comment: Y por que necesitas el settimeout?

Answer (score 1):

**Ejecutar función al finalizar bucle forEach u otra proceso**

Hola, una solución al problema que planteas es usar un callback en la función que hace el bucle forEach. Pues los callback a menudo se utilizan para ejecutar una función cuando cierto proceso a terminado. Dejo un ejemplo para una mayor compresión:

```js
 function recorrerArray(texto,callback){
            
                    let array= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
                    array.forEach( e => console.log( texto, e ) )
                    callback();
                }

        recorrerArray("Paso ", function(){ console.log("El forEach termino ejecutar método Navigator") });
```

**Explicación**

La función recorrerArray realizara un bucle forEach que imprimirá el contenido del array. En este caso, queremos ejecutar una acción cuando el bucle finalice. Por eso, agregamos como parámetro el callback y dentro de la función `callback()` esto nos permitirá definir una función que queremos que se ejecute al final de la iteración del bucle. En este caso imprimir un mensaje. Este principio, lo puedes aplicar a tu código, creando un callback que permita ejecutar el método navigator cuando el bucle finalice de hacer su trabajo. Para su caso podría ser algo así:

```js
let images= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

        async function compartir(images){
    //let filesArray = []

    function bucle(callback){

    images.forEach( async (element) => {
     /* const tmp = element.src.split('/')
      const name = tmp[tmp.length - 1];
      
      const response = await fetch(element.src);
      const blob = await response.blob();
  
      filesArray.push(new File([blob],name, {type:     "image/jpeg",lastModified: new Date().getTime()}))*/     

        console.log(element);
    })

    callback();
                            }

    bucle( function(){ LlamandoMetodo() } )
    
    //setTimeout(() => {
        function LlamandoMetodo(){ 
                    //console.log(filesArray);      
                    //navigator['share']({files: filesArray, title: 'PAGINA DEL PRODUCTO', text: 'texto', url:  '' }) 
                    console.log("Ejecutando metodo Navigator")
                }   
    ///}, 3000);   
  }

        compartir(images)
```